# How to apply condition for the visible Pop ups,

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have application on which, user enter codes, on the bases of the codes a pop appear with result.

But the i find difficulty in apply in codes on the bases of visible pop up. It is not certain which pop appear, this depend only on codes.
[image]

Here is html structure:

```
    <div class="enter-code" style="">
        <div class="code-matched" style="display:none;">
        <div class="hundred" style="display:none;">
        <div class="thousand" style="display:none;">
        <div class="five thosand" style="display:none;">
        <div class="one lakh" style="display:none;">
        <div class="code-not-matched" style="">
                 <span>The code you entered doesn’t match any in our system, please try again.</span>
        </div>
        <div class="code-box" style="display: none;">
   </div>
```

If user enter code and it match with our system then a message is appear in pop and same if not then message appear in same pop up.

Here is code, what is done in Eclipes.

```
  driver.findElement(By.name("nmb")).clear();
  driver.findElement(By.name("nmb")).sendKeys(a1[i]);
  driver.findElement(By.id("reward")).click();      
   Thread.sleep(6000);
    if( driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='code-matched' or  @class='code-for-first' or @class='code-for-second' or @class='code-for-third' or @class='code-for-fouth' or @class='code-not-matched']")).isDisplayed()){
      System.out.println("Hello 1");
        }
      else{
          System.out.println("Hello 1.1");
          }
```

I apply condition in IF condition, but it print RESULT in always in ELSE condition.

Answer (score 1):

Pop ups creates new window handle in `driver.getWindowHandles()`. You can use that to determine if the pop up appears

```
Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
if (handles.size() > 1) {
    System.out.println("Hello 1");
}
```

And to do actions on the pop up you need to switch to it

```
String parentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();

driver.findElement(By.name("nmb")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.name("nmb")).sendKeys(a1[i]);
driver.findElement(By.id("reward")).click();

// find all pop ups
List<WebElement> popUps = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".enter-code > div"));

// wait for pop up to be displayed
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
boolean found = false;
do {
    for (WebElement popUp : popUps) {
        if (popUp.isDisplayed()) {
            String class = popUp.getAttribute("class");
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
} while (!found && (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000 < 5);

// switch to pop up
for (String handle : handles) {
    if (!handle.equals(parentHandle))
    {
        driver.switchTo().window(handle);
    }
}

// switch back to the old window
driver.close(); // close only the pop up
driver.switchTo().window(parentHandle);
```

The `do while` loop will work for 5 seconds or until you found the pop up, the sooner. The `for` loop will iterate over the pop ups until one of them is displayed.

Comment: Here i want to apply condition that wait for the Pop up appear. Any pop up among given in code six classes (code-matched, code-for-first,....). I have to wait until any among six pop up is visible. How i apply?

Comment: Also all pop up have same handle.

Comment: @Mani I added solution for it.

Comment: The handle is changing from run to run even for the same pop up, but you get the new handle each time so it doesn't matter for you.

Comment: Hey, guy thanks 

But where i enters the codes that is pop and result comes in the same pop up,
But what if the pop up have different class name
Like you entered "code- " 
On the above example we have same starting class name what if class name starting does not match?

Comment: I update the class name, now how i apply the explicit wait condition for the given class name.

Comment: explicit wait is not working giving error "By.cssSelector("[class*='code-']" is not visible

Answer (score 1):

Switch to pop-up first and then perform action on pop-up and then switch back to default page.

Try below :-

```
......Your code upto pop-up appear ....

        driver.switchTo().alert();

.... Your code in between actions on pop-up ....

        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Hope this will help you :)